# Managing time from a flask backend server for different countries

Tags: date, flask, time, frontend, backend

I have been working on a web application, the backend is built with flask, frontend with Reactjs, after hosting it, I realized that the time that I was storing at the backend was saved reflecting the location of the server where I hosted the backend. so my question goes.

How do I save date and time at the level of the flask backend, and then convert it in the frontend using the user's location on the browser to reflect the local time of the user?

Would appreciate a kind solution.

Comment: I tried using UTC, but don't really know how it works in python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the conversion at the server level i.e. flask, then you could try something like this, where the client when firing a request to server specifies the timezone it is in(example **US/Pacific** ) and server can respond the details accordingly.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/time')
def time():
    #Default sever level date and time
    current_server_time = datetime.now()
    if 'timezone' in request.args:
        tzinfo = pytz.timezone(request.args['timezone'])
        #Converting date and time based on timeone input from client
        current_client_time = current_server_time.astimezone(tzinfo)
        return jsonify({"time":current_client_time})
    return jsonify({"time":current_server_time})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```

You can try it by accessing **http://localhost:8001/time?timezone=US/Pacific**

You will obviously have to add in validation related to timezone received from the client.

I'm sure you can do conversion at reactjs level as well, as long as the server response specifies timezone.

Comment: Okay @Saurav, if I understand well, I'll need to know the user's timezone first. I was thinking to save time at the level of the server, maybe in a way that will be easily converted on the client-side, no matter the time zone.